# Not able to read JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following code for reading a JSON file.It is giving no error but i am getting null in the variable:

```
var myData = null;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: 'myJson.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (r) {
        myData = r;
    }
});
```

Below is my JSON file:

```
{items:[{value:"1",name:"John"},{value:"2",name:"Henry"}]};
```

Comment: Why not use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead?

Comment: i tried without semicolon also

Comment: check [here](http://jsonlint.com/) for valid or not

Comment: `async : true`.. ajax call should be asynchronous always. and your json is wrong as mentioned by benjamin in below post. Try [**jsonLint**](http://jsonlint.com/) to test whether your json is in correct format or not, always.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Your [JSON is invalid](http://json.org/).

#### An object serialized in JSON is in the following format:

[image]

#### Where string is:

[image]

JSON strings must be escaped. You're missing the `"`s.

A correct JSON would be:

```
{"items":[{"value":"1","name":"John"},{"value":"2","name":"Henry"}]}
```

#### How I created it

Even if I hadn't remembered or looked up the specific JSON rules, you can always produce the JSON from the JS variable assuming it's serializable (in your case it is) by:

- Open a JavaScript console
- Type `var a =`  and paste your object literal
- Press enter.
- Type `JSON.stringify(a)`;
- Press enter. Copy the result.
- Paste the result in your external `.json` file. JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` produces valid JSON.

Comment: When i am putting JSON file directly in variable instead of external file, its working

Comment: It's working because it's a valid JS object literal, not valid JSON.

Comment: @Aquarius24 JSON is a data-exchange format you use to in JS to serialize and de-serialize objects. A JavaScript object literal is _not_ JSON. JSON can be serialized from and de-serialized to JavaScript objects, but it's  stricter. For another example `{"a":3,"b":5,}` is a valid ES5 JavaScript object literal but still invalid JSON because of the trailing `,`

Comment: Thanks all, that was the only problem...:)